# Binary reader from c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, binary

I have a binary reader in c++ and i am trying to write the same thing in python (beginner in both language). I read online and i see that i should use struct but i am having trouble getting it done.
My c++ code is the Following:

```
    struct databin {
        float prixc[60];
        float volume[60];
    };
    databin qt;
    //get the data for day d, minute i//
    int numsteps = m_nbsteps * sizeof(qt);
    int step = d*numsteps+i*sizeof(qt);
    m_rf.seekg(step, ios::beg); 
    m_rf.read((char*) &qt, sizeof(qt));
// at the end we have the data in the object qt
```

I would really appreciate some help to do the same in python.
Thank you!!

update:
Sorry Mark, i did not want my message to be perceived that way. Really appreciate the time you spend.

Actually i was more looking for a starting point with "struct"   as my struct in c was made of two arrays and i cant find how to have the same type of structure in python to be able to use unpack.

What i have done so far:

```
//get the data for day d, minute i//

d=5000

i=15    

numsteps=391*480

x=[]

y=[]

step=d*numsteps+i*480

with open(file, "rb") as of: 

    of.seek(step, 0) 

    couple_bytes = of.read(480)

    for j in range(0,240,4):

        [x] = struct.unpack('f', couple_bytes[j:j+4])

        xx.append(x)

    for j in range(244,480,4):

        [y] = struct.unpack('f', couple_bytes[j:j+4])   

        yy.append(y)
```

Now this works and in xx and yy i have my 2 arrays. But my goal was to have a more direct approach by defining a structure and reading it directly.

Thank you again!

Comment: Look at the `struct` module.

Comment: Thank you but as i told in the message i already got that...Was looking for a bit more help

Comment: This isn't a code writing service.  Read the documentation and if you still don't understand, come back and ask a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

The [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings) module has the ability to unpack many values at a time by including a count in the format string.

```
with open(file, "rb") as of: 
    of.seek(step, 0) 
    couple_bytes = of.read(60*4)
    prixc = list(struct.unpack('60f', couple_bytes))
    couple_bytes = of.read(60*4)
    volume = list(struct.unpack('60f', couple_bytes))
```